# C# PushBroker: ChannelCreated get called but not NotificationFailed or NotificationSent

Tags: c#, push-notification

*I am trying to Send Apple Push Notification. And, only **ChannelCreated** event gets called at my end, and not **NotificationFailed or NotificationSent**. Also,Notification does not gets sent to that specific Apple Device. I have also run telnet command to fix this issue, but in vain.*

```
 public static void SendApplePushNotification(string DeviceToken, String PostData)
        {
            try
            {
                string AppleapiPassKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplePushPassword"];
                //AppleapiPassKey = string.Empty;
                var push = new PushBroker();

                push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
                push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
                push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
                push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
                push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
                push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
                push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
                push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

                var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin/private_key_noenc.p12"));

                //push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true,appleCert, AppleapiPassKey)); //Extension method
                push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, AppleapiPassKey)); //Extension method



                var message = new Message() { ChainId = 12, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Message1 = "hi how are you" };
                push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                                  .ForDeviceToken(DeviceToken)
                                  .WithAlert(PostData)
                                  .WithSound("Default")
                    //.WithCustomItem("content-available", message)
                    //.WithContentAvailable(1)
                                  );

                //push.StopAllServices(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError.LogErrorToFile(ex);
            }
        }

        public static void DeviceSubscriptionChanged(object sender,
        string oldSubscriptionId, string newSubscriptionId, INotification notification)
        {
        }


        public static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
        {
        }
        public static void NotificationFailed(object sender,
        INotification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
        {
        }

        public static void ChannelException
            (object sender, IPushChannel channel, Exception exception)
        {
        }

        public static void ServiceException(object sender, Exception exception)
        {
        }


        public static void DeviceSubscriptionExpired(object sender,
        string expiredDeviceSubscriptionId,
            DateTime timestamp, INotification notification)
        {
        }

        public static void ChannelDestroyed(object sender)
        {
        }

        public static void ChannelCreated(object sender, IPushChannel pushChannel)
        {
        }
```

Comment: I'm working on memory, but I think you can uncomment `stopAllServices`. My best first guess is to check that the ports are open for apple push notifications. I think they're somewhere in the 2000s.

Comment: Millie, Uncommenting push.StopAllServices hangs up the process, and, it also is not giving any exception

Comment: I don't remember mine throwing exceptions when the ports were blocked. It was 6 - 12 months ago, though.